# Why is my json formatted string not getting converted into json array by using swiftyjson library in swift 3

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am trying to convert the following string which I am getting as string response from a server into the json array using swift json in ios. But it is not getting converted into string.

Here is my string:

> [{\"Sno\":\"1\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5511\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DGSE\",\"Applied_Date\":\"09-Jun-2016\",\"Description\":\"hahahha\",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed
>   Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6290\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DGSE\",\"Action_Date\":\"28-Jun-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740688052\"},{\"Sno\":\"2\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5516\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DGSE\",\"Applied_Date\":\"09-Jun-2016\",\"Description\":\"\n\n\n\n\n\n\",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed
>   Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6290\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DGSE\",\"Action_Date\":\"28-Jun-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740674400\"},{\"Sno\":\"3\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5522\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DGSE\",\"Applied_Date\":\"12-Jun-2016\",\"Description\":\"testing
>   testing testing testing testing testing
>   \",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed
>   Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6290\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DGSE\",\"Action_Date\":\"28-Jun-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740663938\"},{\"Sno\":\"4\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5529\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"CEO(Nabha)\",\"Applied_Date\":\"13-Jun-2016\",\"Description\":\"testing.
>   \",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Pending\",\"Action_Code\":\"\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"CEO(Nabha)\",\"Action_Date\":\"\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740659500\"},{\"Sno\":\"5\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5530\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DGSE\",\"Applied_Date\":\"13-Jun-2016\",\"Description\":\"bbbnnnnnnbbbvvvvvvbbbbvbbbb\",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed
>   Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6290\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DGSE\",\"Action_Date\":\"28-Jun-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740647081\"},{\"Sno\":\"6\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5531\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DGSE\",\"Applied_Date\":\"13-Jun-2016\",\"Description\":\"
>   vvbhhhhhhhhhhgvg. vvbhhhhhhhhhhgvg.  \",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed
>   Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6290\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DGSE\",\"Action_Date\":\"28-Jun-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740634790\"},{\"Sno\":\"7\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5532\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DGSE\",\"Applied_Date\":\"13-Jun-2016\",\"Description\":\"I
>   m in
>   prakshvtadavhjhgggggggggggghggghhhg\",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed
>   Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6290\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DGSE\",\"Action_Date\":\"28-Jun-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740678909\"},{\"Sno\":\"8\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5728\",\"CaseType\":\"Increment
>   related\",\"MarkedTo\":\"CEO(Jalandhar)\",\"Applied_Date\":\"01-Aug-2016\",\"Description\":\"rigorous
>   testing is the most mandatory step towards developing robust software
>   \",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed
>   Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6718\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"CEO(Jalandhar)\",\"Action_Date\":\"12-Aug-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740611379\"},{\"Sno\":\"9\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5884\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DGSE\",\"Applied_Date\":\"10-Sep-2016\",\"Description\":\"hellovvnnbvccccdccxxxccccccvv\",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed
>   Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6290\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DGSE\",\"Action_Date\":\"12-Sep-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740697305\"},{\"Sno\":\"10\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5885\",\"CaseType\":\"Probation
>   Period related\",\"MarkedTo\":\"Director
>   (SCERT)\",\"Applied_Date\":\"10-Sep-2016\",\"Description\":\"vgccgggcgggggvbvvhbbvvbbbbbbbb\",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Pending\",\"Action_Code\":\"\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"Director
>   (SCERT)\",\"Action_Date\":\"\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740686213\"},{\"Sno\":\"11\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"6176\",\"CaseType\":\"ACR\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DEO(EE)-BATHINDA\",\"Applied_Date\":\"05-Jan-2017\",\"Description\":\"Addedczxvxvxvdzvdgdsdgdsxgdgdsgdfgdsgdss\",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Pending\",\"Action_Code\":\"\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DEO(EE)-BATHINDA\",\"Action_Date\":\"\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740618188\"}]

Here is my code:

```
if let dataFromString = string.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {

        let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)                                           
        var i=0

        for i in 0..<json.count {    

        }
}
```

it is always giving json count of 0. Kindly help.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: why? pls tell. It seems valid to me

Comment: @rajvirsingh All those `\ ` before every `"` cannot be in JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally find the solution to my own problem. The problem with the conversion in json from the string was that it contains \n character. Swifty json library which I am using to convert the string into ios is giving me an error at the time of conversion due to the presence of \n characer. I removed the \n character and it converted without any trouble. So, the catch is to remove the special escape characters when converting from a string to json format using swifty json library in ios though i dont know about the other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
let swiftyJsonVar = "[{\"Sno\":\"1\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5511\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DGSE\",\"Applied_Date\":\"09-Jun-2016\",\"Description\":\"hahahha\",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6290\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DGSE\",\"Action_Date\":\"28-Jun-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740688052\"},{\"Sno\":\"2\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5516\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DGSE\",\"Applied_Date\":\"09-Jun-2016\",\"Description\":\"\",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6290\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DGSE\",\"Action_Date\":\"28-Jun-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740674400\"},{\"Sno\":\"3\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5522\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DGSE\",\"Applied_Date\":\"12-Jun-2016\",\"Description\":\"testing testing testing testing testing testing \",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6290\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DGSE\",\"Action_Date\":\"28-Jun-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740663938\"},{\"Sno\":\"4\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5529\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"CEO(Nabha)\",\"Applied_Date\":\"13-Jun-2016\",\"Description\":\"testing. \",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Pending\",\"Action_Code\":\"\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"CEO(Nabha)\",\"Action_Date\":\"\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740659500\"},{\"Sno\":\"5\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5530\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DGSE\",\"Applied_Date\":\"13-Jun-2016\",\"Description\":\"bbbnnnnnnbbbvvvvvvbbbbvbbbb\",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6290\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DGSE\",\"Action_Date\":\"28-Jun-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740647081\"},{\"Sno\":\"6\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5531\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DGSE\",\"Applied_Date\":\"13-Jun-2016\",\"Description\":\" vvbhhhhhhhhhhgvg. vvbhhhhhhhhhhgvg. \",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6290\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DGSE\",\"Action_Date\":\"28-Jun-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740634790\"},{\"Sno\":\"7\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5532\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DGSE\",\"Applied_Date\":\"13-Jun-2016\",\"Description\":\"I m in prakshvtadavhjhgggggggggggghggghhhg\",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6290\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DGSE\",\"Action_Date\":\"28-Jun-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740678909\"},{\"Sno\":\"8\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5728\",\"CaseType\":\"Increment related\",\"MarkedTo\":\"CEO(Jalandhar)\",\"Applied_Date\":\"01-Aug-2016\",\"Description\":\"rigorous testing is the most mandatory step towards developing robust software \",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6718\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"CEO(Jalandhar)\",\"Action_Date\":\"12-Aug-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740611379\"},{\"Sno\":\"9\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5884\",\"CaseType\":\"ACP\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DGSE\",\"Applied_Date\":\"10-Sep-2016\",\"Description\":\"hellovvnnbvccccdccxxxccccccvv\",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Disposed Off\",\"Action_Code\":\"6290\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DGSE\",\"Action_Date\":\"12-Sep-2016\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740697305\"},{\"Sno\":\"10\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"5885\",\"CaseType\":\"Probation Period related\",\"MarkedTo\":\"Director (SCERT)\",\"Applied_Date\":\"10-Sep-2016\",\"Description\":\"vgccgggcgggggvbvvhbbvvbbbbbbbb\",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Pending\",\"Action_Code\":\"\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"Director (SCERT)\",\"Action_Date\":\"\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740686213\"},{\"Sno\":\"11\",\"Grivence_Code\":\"6176\",\"CaseType\":\"ACR\",\"MarkedTo\":\"DEO(EE)-BATHINDA\",\"Applied_Date\":\"05-Jan-2017\",\"Description\":\"Addedczxvxvxvdzvdgdsdgdsxgdgdsgdfgdsgdss\",\"CurrentStatus\":\"Pending\",\"Action_Code\":\"\",\"Action_TakenBy\":\"DEO(EE)-BATHINDA\",\"Action_Date\":\"\",\"Remarks\":\"\",\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"GrievanceNumber\":\"10740618188\"}]"
let finalJSON = JSON.parse(swiftyJsonVar)

print(finalJSON.arrayObject);
// you can use any of this to get your desired object
//print(finalJSON.arrayValue);
//print(finalJSON.array);
```

[[image: Result]]

Comment: Please include an explanation as to why your code might help OP